# How to convert .tlrc file to .orig file?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, fmri

I have files: `left_fg+tlrc.BRIK` and `left_fg+tlrc.HEAD`. I want to know 
how to convert the files to `left_fg+orig.BRIK` and `left_fg+orig.HEAD`. 
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get these files from? Are they just text files? Are they related to a specific program?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for StackOverflow or SuperUser

Comment: This question would not at all be appropriate for StackOverflow or SuperUser. It's not about programming. It's about transforming MRI data from Talairach space back to its original coordinates. OP is using AFNI for data analysis. Please don't vote to close because you don't understand the question, but request clarification instead.